# Elastic Search Prioritize search results that begin with the search term

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search, search-engine

***I need to prioritize search results that start with the search term. I used "match_phrase_prefix". I used "match_phrase_prefix". But isn't working.***

Details:

- Query

  ```
       GET /test/products/_search?pretty
          { 
            "query": {
              "match_phrase_prefix": {
               "title": "iphone 5c"
              }
            }
          }
  ```
- Result

  ```
      "_score": 10.440153
      title": "Capa de Tpu para Iphone 5c Modelo Apple + Película"

  "_score": 9.981493,
  "title": "Capa Bumper Iphone 5C + Pelicula",

  "_score": 8.610232
  "title": "Pelicula Protetora para Iphone 5C Transparente"

  "_score": 5.154923,
  "title": "iPhone 5c Apple 8GB com Tela de 4”, iOS7, Câmera 8MP, Touch Screen, Wi-Fi, 3G/4G, GPS, MP3 e Bluetooth - Rosa"

  "_score": 5.154923
  "title": "iPhone 5c Apple 8GB com Tela de 4”, iOS7, Câmera 8MP, Touch Screen, Wi-Fi, 3G/4G, GPS, MP3 e Bluetooth - Branco"

  "_score": 5.154923
  "title": "iPhone 5c Apple 8GB com Tela de 4”, iOS7, Câmera 8MP, Touch Screen, Wi-Fi, 3G/4G, GPS, MP3 e Bluetooth - Preto"
  ```
- Mappings

  ```
      "mappings": {
          "products": {
            "properties": {
              "title": {
                 "type": "string",
                 "analyzer": "brazilian"
              }
            }
          }
      }
  ```

> In this example I need the first result is the device (Iphone 5c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the use of analyser which is causing tokenization problem. Have a look below how your document field is getting tokenized.

You need to use keyword tokenizer.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_analyze?analyzer=standard&pretty' -d 'Capa Bumper Iphone 5C' | grep token
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   532  100   511  100    21  32800   1347 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 34066
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "capa",
    "token" : "bumper",
    "token" : "iphone",
    "token" : "5c",
```

Add a keyword tokenizer in your mapping:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/starts-with-phrase-matching

Comment: In the case of capturing the first token, as would be?